# spark 1.6 does sqlContext.read.json triggers action ? how to avoid that

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

reading a sequence file with json format records .

1. read input sequence file
2. sqlcontext.read.json() to convert into dataframe
3. select subset data from above data frame  and cache.

the issue I am facing is when spark gets to step 2 seems like it triggers action hence reads input data and creates a dataframe.

but when I get to step 3  since its a cache triggering action to materialize DF, it reads the input data again hence wasting time reading input data twice.

I do not want to cache the input data.

how to avoid reading the input data twice  ?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to save the dataframe read after `sqlcontext.read.json()` and read back and then do caching for subsequent processes.

You can do `dataframe checkpointing` or save it to HDFS to achieve that.

This will eliminate the multiple reading of input sequence file